# Joi validation how to ref for brackets using

Tags: node.js, typescript, joi

```
{
"visibleFields": {
  "design.content.buttons.action.type": {
    "SHOW_CLOSE": true,
    "URL": true,
    "CALL_PHONE": true
  },
  "design.content.formFields": false,
  "success": false,
  "design.appearance.closeButtons": true,
  "design.appearance.backgroundOverlay": true,
  "design.appearance.button": true,
  "design.content.privacyPolicy": false,
  "design.content.wheel": false,
  "design.appearance.formFields": false,
  "design.content.description": true,
  "design.appearance.customCss": true,
  "design.content.headline": true,
  "design.appearance.displayEffect": true,
  "design.layout.floatingbar": true,
  "design.layout": true,
  "design.appearance.body": true,
  "design.content.buttons": true,
  "design.content.images": false
}}
```

I have json construction as above. I want to get "visibleFields.design.content.images" using ref, but it doesn't work. Normally I can access it using "visibleFields['design.content.images']" like this, but I could not achieve it in the schema. How can I solve this problem?

```
images: Joi.when(Joi.ref('...visibleFields.design.content.images'), {
      is: false,
      then: Joi.array().length(0),
      otherwise: Joi.array().items(
        Joi.object().keys({
          type: Joi.string(),
          label: Joi.string(),
          backgroundColor: Joi.string(),
          size: Joi.number().integer(),
          horizontal: Joi.number().integer(),
          vertical: Joi.number().integer(),
          repeatMode: Joi.string(),
          hide: Joi.boolean(),
          value: Joi.string().uri(),
        }),
      ),
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `.` separator with the `{ seperator: false }` option

```
images: Joi.when(Joi.ref('...visibleFields.design.content.images', { seperator: false }), {
      is: false,
      then: Joi.array().length(0),
      otherwise: Joi.array().items(
        Joi.object().keys({
          type: Joi.string(),
          label: Joi.string(),
          backgroundColor: Joi.string(),
          size: Joi.number().integer(),
          horizontal: Joi.number().integer(),
          vertical: Joi.number().integer(),
          repeatMode: Joi.string(),
          hide: Joi.boolean(),
          value: Joi.string().uri(),
        }),
      ),
    })
```